# C#,unity and Mqtt

Tags: c#, mqtt

Hello I just started in C #. I am using C # for unity for student project. Normally all code works up to the private void ToggleUI (bool _value) function. Once arrived at private void Subscribe () the problems start. When I compile my code I get an error that I don't understand "the type or namespace name MqttMsgPublishEventArgs could not be found". Here is the code in question. could you give me any clue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Waypoint1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Image iconImg;
    private Text distanceText;
    public Transform player;
    public Transform target;
    public Camera cam;
    
    public float closeEnoughDist;
    
    private void Start()
    {
      iconImg=GetComponent<Image>();
      distanceText=GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    }

    
    private void Update()
    {
        if(target != null)
            target.position = new Vector3(7f, 0, 5f);
            GetDistance();
            CheckOnScreen();
    }
    
    private void GetDistance()
    {
        float dist=Vector3.Distance(player.position, target.position);
        distanceText.text=dist.ToString("f1") +"m";
        
        if(dist<closeEnoughDist)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        
    }
    
    private void CheckOnScreen()
    {
        float thing=Vector3.Dot((target.position-cam.transform.position).normalized, cam.transform.forward);
        if(thing<=0)
            ToggleUI(false);
        else
            ToggleUI(true);
            transform.position=cam.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
            
    }
    
    private void ToggleUI(bool _value)
    {
        iconImg.enabled=_value;
        distanceText.enabled=_value;
    }
    
    
    private void Subscribe()
    {
        // create client instance (both host name and IP address work nicely)
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("<10.214.0.163>");

        // register to message received 
        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.Connect(clientId);
    
        // subscribe to the topic "unity" with QoS 2 
        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "unity" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
    }

     void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle message received 
        Console.WriteLine("Received = " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message) + " on topic " + e.Topic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is that your code cannot find the argument `MqttMsgPublishEventArgs` in `client_MqttMsgPublishReceived`. Are you missing a `using` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing these using statements:

```
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
```

This is a sample project that should help you out:
https://github.com/gpvigano/M2MqttUnity